# Remove all loggers from winston container

Tags: winston

How do I remove all winston loggers?

I need to do this during testing.

Note that `winston.clear()` and `winston.remove()` are used to remove transports, whereas I want to remove the loggers themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a method to remove all loggers but to end a specific logger you can call

```
winston.loggers.close(id);
```

If you're keeping track of all your loggers you could just loop through and kill them off.

Answer (score 0):

### I found a code that removes all Loggers.

Analyzing [Winston's source code](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/fcc69eca84e299d158872c2cac0871f4898a3a96/lib/winston/container.js#L89), I found in the `close` method that it removes all loggers when no `id` is informed